# click of a button which creates a new item in a dropdown menu living in the ActionBar - android developing

Tags: android, button, drop-down-menu, click, menuitem

I have been creating my first app in android.
Now I have a serious problem which I cannot solve and cannot find someone in the web who coded something similar.
I would like to have a button which adds an item to a menu,
represented by a text "Hello". Such a menu is actually a dropdown menu which appears at a click of a button living in the ActionBar.
My code follows:
MainActivity.java

```
package com.mycompany.aad;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.SubMenu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Menu menu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });




        Button buttonX = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_additem);
        buttonX.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Hello");
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);


        this.menu = menu;

        //the menu option text is defined in resources


        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }
```

menu_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_new_form"
    android:icon="@drawable/arrow"
    android:title="arrow"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom">
    <menu
        android:id="@+id/submenu">
    <item android:id="@+id/create_new"
        android:title="eganaude" />
    <item android:id="@+id/open"
        android:title="skema" />
    </menu>

</item></menu>
```

My problem is that the line of code:

```
menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Hello");
```

which should do the trick, adds an item in the menu appearing at a click of the classical "three points" button of the ActionBar, and if (as in my case) such button doesn't exist yet, it is created at the click.
How can I choose to make the item appear in my menu whose id is defined in:

```
android:id="@+id/submenu"
```

?
Any help is appreciated.